# Not Sure How to Update Bool Values in Plist from UISwitch in UITableViewCell

Tags: xcode, uitableview, boolean, plist, uiswitch

I have a table with four rows, each having a title and switch as an accessory. I would like for the plist Boolean value to be updated when the corresponding switch is tapped.

Plist:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Bools</key>
        <array>
            <false/>
            <false/>
            <false/>
            <false/>
        </array>
        <key>Strings</key>
        <array>
            <string>String0</string>
            <string>String1</string>
            <string>String2</string>
            <string>String3</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Here are the data source methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView; {
return [allergens count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section; {
return [[[allergens objectAtIndex: section] objectForKey: @"Strings"] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section; {
return @"Header";
}
```

Here is my switch, with selector: switchToggled

```
UISwitch *switchView = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
cell.accessoryView = switchView;
[switchView addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Below is the IBAction method. I can successfully get the `switch tapped` to appear in the log, so I know everything works. I am just not sure how to get the correct Boolean value to be updated.

```
- (IBAction)switchToggled:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"switch tapped");
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: You need to update model after the switch has pressed. And use this model to update switch state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was so new to programming when I posted this I was not aware that I could not programmatically edit a plist in the main bundle at runtime. I now understand that to achieve the effect I want I should save the starting plist to the app documents directory and work from that. I used [this](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/05/30/property-list-tutorial-using-plist-to-store-user-data/) article to help format the process of saving and loading data to and from the documents directory.